# Load a module from app/*/*/some_module.rb directly into the global namespace

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Rails loads files from `app/models/concerns` and `app/controllers/concerns` directly into the global namespace instead of the `Concerns` namespace.

So if you define a module `SomeConcern` at `app/models/concerns/some_concern.rb`, instead of `Concerns::SomeConcern`, you have just `SomeConcern` available.

I would like to add a `concerns` folder in another subdirectory of `app` that behaves the same way. More specifically: I want to define `SomeSerializerConcern` at `app/serializers/concerns/some_serializer_concern.rb`, but currently it's only working if I define the module as `Concerns::SomeSerializerConcern`.

I have this line in config/application.rb:

`config.paths.add "app/serializers/concerns", eager_load: true`

[This excellent post](http://blog.arkency.com/2014/11/dont-forget-about-eager-load-when-extending-autoload/) on autoload and eager_load led me to believe that this is how Rails itself accomplishes what I want to do, but it doesn't seem to work in this scenario. I'm using Rails 4.2.6.  Any ideas?

Comment: If your module's in a namespace it will be loaded in a namespace. If you want it at the root, move it to the root. You can set up something like `app/concerns` and it should work as expected.

Comment: @tadman That would work, but I'd prefer to be consistent with the folder structure of `models` and `controllers` and keep my serializer-specific concerns under `serializers`... or presenter concerns with presenters, or authorizer concerns with authorizers, etc. It's clearly not worth it if it requires some hideous hack, but Rails itself is clearly breaking the namespace rule to the follow this pattern, so I thought there might be a relatively simple way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out this [gist](https://gist.github.com/maxim/6503591) provides the answer.

All I needed to do was add the path directly to eager_load_paths in `config/application.rb`:

```
config.eager_load_paths += [Rails.root.join('lib'),
                            Rails.root.join('app', 'serializers', 'concerns')]
```

Comment: This will do it, but it's a bit non-standard. You may want to add a note in your README as to this quirk, or at least commend that line in case someone else discovers it and is confused. Often that "someone" is yourself in the future.